# Magento - Logout when browser close

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

User is logging into magento (without checking Remember Me option) and closes the browser without logging out from magento system. Now if the user opens a browser window again, it should be logged out. How do I do that in magento?

Comment: You need to set cookie params unit the browser is closed.

Comment: It's working, if we clear cookies manually. But in magento way?

Comment: you can set the cookie lifetime form magento backend

Comment: Yes, I tried to set 0, but again login is not happening if I set 0.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP,

```
session_set_cookie_params(0);
```

Normally a cookie lifetime of "0" means "when the browser exits".

You can set the cookie lifetime form magento backend but keep in mind that this will also affect the session lifetime of the admin panel. So if you log in to the admin panel and you don't use it for a while, you'll be automatically logged out after the cookie lifetime expires.

**Frontend (session) cookie**

In Magento, the 'frontend' cookie gets set right before the current action is being dispatched.

Have a look at `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::preDispatch()`.

**Session start**

Looking into `preDispatch():`

`Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => $namespace))->start();`

Which (if not overridden) finally maps to

`Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien::start()`

This is the place where all the standard session gets initialized and that includes cookie settings by using `session_set_cookie_params`.

Revalidation

Also you need to be aware that the constructor calls `revalidateCookie()` while instantiating the core session:

`Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien::init()`

Comment: Did u check my comment? login is not happening if I put 0 in backend